# VB.NET: How to retrieve a compressed web page to a string?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I'm trying to pull some text to sort from a website.

Using a function like this:

```
Private Function GetContent(ByRef strUrlAddress as String) as String

     Dim ResultString as String = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(strUrlAddress)
     Return ResultString

End Function
```

Retrieves the text from some sites fine. But other sites are returning compressed data, and the string ends up containing blobs of data. How do I retrieve the decompressed page, or decompress the data as its retrieved?

Comment: Can you provide publicly accessible examples?

Comment: @dummy easiest demo for me is using curl to get api.stackexchange.com, then retrieve api.stackexchange.com/sites (it's in the docs it's always compressed JSON). The second site will be data, but if you use curl --compressed you see text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution came from searches that had examples in C# for .NET.

```
  Dim strSitesReply As String = ""

Try
     Dim Request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(strUrlAddress)
     ' Here is the important part, using .AutomaticDecompression
     Request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate
     Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Request.GetResponse()
     Using Reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream())
          strSitesReply = Reader.ReadToEnd()
     End Using
Catch ex As Exception
     MsgBox("Error: " + ex.Message)
end Try
```

After adding that line, retrieving even compressed sites seemed to now work properly.