# Web crawler in NodeJS - Encrypted page or something like

Tags: node.js, web-crawler

I'm trying to extract some data from a website, so I wrote kind of a web crawler in NodeJS.

The problem is that the page is returning the HTML encoded, like this:

```
</�◄♣b∟�♣66c���▬�iǌi�g��-��~\��r>
```

What is this and how can I "fix it"?

### UPDATE

```
var http = require('follow-redirects').http;

// Utility function that downloads a URL and invokes
// callback with the data.
function download(url, callback) {

    var request_options = {
        host: url,
        headers: {
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36'
        },
        path: '/'
    };

    http.get(url, function (res) {
        var data = "";
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            data += chunk;
        });
        res.on("end", function () {
            callback(data);
        });
    }).on("error", function () {
        callback(null);
    });
}

var cheerio = require("cheerio");

var baseUrl = "http://www.mensagemaniversario.com.br";

var fs = require("fs");

var Entities = require('html-entities').AllHtmlEntities;

entities = new Entities();

var page = 1;

function recursiveDownload(url) {
    download(url, function (data) {
        if (data) {
            // console.log(data);
            var $ = cheerio.load(data);
            console.log($.html());
            $("div.box-list > p").each(function (i, e) {
                var frase = $(e);


                fs.appendFile("dados.xml", "<frase>" + entities.decode(frase.html()) + "</frase>");
            });

            console.log("Processado página " + url);
            var linkNextPage = $("div.pagination a:last-child");
            if (linkNextPage.length > 0) {
                page++;
                recursiveDownload(baseUrl + linkNextPage.attr("href"));
            }
        }
    });
}

recursiveDownload(baseUrl + '/15-anos');
```

Comment: Can't see the encoded HTML code you added.

Comment: Sorry. Question updated

Comment: Also if it's not secret could you add the code and the web page url ?

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but to make it easier for anyone else looking for the same answer, it is because the web page is compressed (ex. Zipped).

Following posts has remedy that worked for me.

[VB.NET: How to retrieve a compressed web page to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908143/vb-net-how-to-retrieve-a-compressed-web-page-to-a-string)